# webgrid mvc3 searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and **webgrid** on a system. I like to know if it's possible to implement a search engine.

My controller has

```
Return View(service.list)
```

and return around 50000 records, so it will be nice to search something inside results.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution....

**The view** (using Razor):

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("ListarAsegurados", "PolizasLayout", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "divGrid"})
    Dim varCondicionesDeBusqueda As IDictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    If Not IsNothing(TempData("CondicionesDeBusqueda")) Then
        varCondicionesDeBusqueda = TryCast(TempData("CondicionesDeBusqueda"), Dictionary(Of String, String))
    End If
    TempData("CondicionesDeBusqueda") = varCondicionesDeBusqueda
    Dim varDocumentoAsegurado As String = If(varCondicionesDeBusqueda.Keys.Contains("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO"), varCondicionesDeBusqueda("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO"), String.Empty)
    Dim varNombresAsegurado As String = If(varCondicionesDeBusqueda.Keys.Contains("Asegurado"), varCondicionesDeBusqueda("Asegurado"), String.Empty)

    @<fieldset>
        <legend>Filtros de Búsqueda</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton("Grupo", "", True, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:30px", .id = "RadioButton1", .onclick = "CambiarEstadoControles(this)"})
                </td>
                <td style="border-width:0px; width:120px">
                    @Html.Label("ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", "Tipo Documento:")
                </td>
                <td style="border-width:0px">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", Nothing, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:250px"})
                </td>
                <td style="width:50px"></td>
                <td style="border-width:0px">
                    @Html.Label("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO", "No. Documento:")
                    @Html.TextBox("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO", varDocumentoAsegurado, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:200px", .onkeyup = "if(this.value.match(/\D/))this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton("Grupo", "", False, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:30px", .id = "RadioButton2", .onclick = "CambiarEstadoControles(this)"})
                </td>
                <td style="border-width:0px; width:120px">
                    @Html.Label("Asegurado", "Apellidos / Nombres:")
                </td>
                <td style="border-width:0px">
                    @Html.TextBox("Asegurado", varNombresAsegurado, New With {.class = "letraingreso", .style = "width:400px; text-transform:uppercase", .disabled = "disabled"})
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-width:0px; width:145px">
                    <input type ="submit" value="Buscar" style="width:90px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>


    @<br />
    @<p>
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Asegurado", New With {.area = "Polizas"}, New With {.class = "imgNuevo"})
    </p>


    @<div id="divGrid">
        @grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle:="webgrid",
                    headerStyle:="webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle:="webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle:="webgrid-alternating-row",
                    selectedRowStyle:="webgrid-selected-row",
                    rowStyle:="webgrid-row-style",
                    mode:=WebGridPagerModes.All,
                    firstText:="<< Inicio",
                    previousText:="< Anterior",
                    nextText:="Siguiente >",
                    lastText:="Fin >>",
                    columns:=grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column(format:=Function(Model) Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", "Asegurado", New With {.area = "Polizas", .parID = Model.ID_ASEGURADO}, New With {.class = "imgEditar", .title = "Modificar"}), style:="webgrid-width-images"),
                    grid.Column(format:=Function(Model) Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", "Asegurado", New With {.area = "Polizas", .parID = Model.ID_ASEGURADO}, New With {.class = "imgEliminar", .title = "Eliminar"}), style:="webgrid-width-images"),
                    grid.Column("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO", "No. Documento"),
                    grid.Column("PRIMER_APELLIDO_ASEGURADO", "Asegurado", format:=Function(Model) Model.PRIMER_APELLIDO_ASEGURADO & " " & Model.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO_ASEGURADO & " " & Model.NOMBRES_ASEGURADO),
                    grid.Column("DIRECCION_DOMICILIO_ASEGURADO", "Dirección"),
                    grid.Column("EMAIL_ASEGURADO", "eMail")
                    )
                    )
    </div>
End Using
```

**Controller**:

```
Function ListarAsegurados() As ActionResult
        Dim varListado As SelectList
        Dim varCondicionesDeBusqueda As IDictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        If Request.Form.AllKeys.Length > 0 Then
            varCondicionesDeBusqueda.Add("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO", Request("DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO"))
            varCondicionesDeBusqueda.Add("Asegurado", Request("Asegurado"))
        Else
            Dim values As Object = Nothing
            If TempData.TryGetValue("CondicionesDeBusqueda", values) Then
                varCondicionesDeBusqueda = TryCast(values, Dictionary(Of String, String))
            End If
        End If

        TempData("CondicionesDeBusqueda") = varCondicionesDeBusqueda
        Dim varDocumentoAsegurado As String = GetSearchConditionValue(varCondicionesDeBusqueda, "DOCUMENTO_ASEGURADO")
        Dim varNombresAsegurado As String = GetSearchConditionValue(varCondicionesDeBusqueda, "Asegurado")

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(varDocumentoAsegurado) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(varNombresAsegurado) Then
            varListado = New SelectList(varServicio.ListarTiposDocumentos, "ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", "DESC_TIPO_DOCUMENTO")
            ViewData("ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO") = varListado

            Return View(varServicio.ListarAsegurados)
        Else
            varListado = New SelectList(varServicio.ListarTiposDocumentos, "ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", "DESC_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", CLng(Request.Form("ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO")))
            ViewData("ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO") = varListado

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(varDocumentoAsegurado) Then
                Return View(varServicio.ListarAseguradosPorApellidosNombres(varNombresAsegurado))
            Else
                Return View(varServicio.ListarAseguradosPorDocumento(CLng(varListado.Items(0).ID_TIPO_DOCUMENTO), varDocumentoAsegurado))
            End If
        End If
    End Function
```

**The function**:

```
Public Function GetSearchConditionValue(ByVal parCondicionesDeBusqueda As IDictionary(Of String, String), ByVal parClave As String) As String
    Dim varValorTemporal As String = String.Empty

    'If parCondicionesDeBusqueda IsNot Nothing AndAlso parCondicionesDeBusqueda.Keys.Contains("StudentName") Then
    If parCondicionesDeBusqueda IsNot Nothing Then
        parCondicionesDeBusqueda.TryGetValue(parClave, varValorTemporal)
    End If
    Return varValorTemporal
End Function
```

You can found the original post at http://www.cnblogs.com/jack86514/archive/2010/10/26/1861109.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the search by filtering your result.

You can add a textbox with the field to search and before returning all your result filter with the content of your textbox

Comment: I already tried but when the results are paging the textbox text used to search lost (on change page) even if I put  **ViewData("mytextbox") = Request.Form("mytextbox")** to keep the searching filter.

Comment: Do you know of a cleaner way to do this? The solution works, but gets very bulky for additional parameters.